# New to statnet in r, error in .Call message

Tags: r, statnet

I'm using statnet and R for the first time, and keep coming across this error message:

Error in .Call(getEdgeAttribute_R, el, attrname, na.omit, null.na, deleted.edges.omit) :
NULL value passed as symbol address

I have not had this problem in any other packages that I've used. And I have not been able to locate any other threads/questions with this error in statnet.

Any help and/or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working case demonstating this error?

Comment: > library(statnet)
> library(UserNetR)
> data(Moreno)
> network.size(Moreno)
[1] 33
> components(Moreno)
Error in .Call(getEdgeAttribute_R, el, attrname, na.omit, null.na, deleted.edges.omit) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address <br/>

Comment: Or another example <br/> > netmat1 <- rbind (c(0,1,1,0,0),
+                   c(0,0,1,1,0),
+                   c(0,0,1,0,0),
+                   c(1,1,1,1,1),
+                   c(1,01,0,0,1))
> rownames(netmat1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
> colnames(netmat1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
> net1 <- network(netmat1, matric.type = "adjacency")
Error in .Call(setVertexAttribute_R, x, attrname, value, v) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
> class(net1)
Error: object 'net1' not found

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the package?

Comment: I just installed the package, and ran your code, and it works (produces a nice plot when plotted)

Comment: Hi Sirius - thank you for trying. I'm glad it worked for you, but obviously frustrated it isn't working on my end! I have installed, uninstalled, and installed again a few different times. If it works for you, at least now I know the problem is internal to my computer.

Comment: Which OS is it? Do an `update.packages( ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE )` in case it relies on a fresher version of something else

Comment: Windows. Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but the same error message returned when I reloaded statnet and tried again.

Comment: which R version is this?

Comment: R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)